# AngularJs - Make form valid manually

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have form with multiple textboxes. If user leaves a field blank he will be shown a checkbox under the form, if the user selects the checkbox then form can be submitted inspite of fields empty.

So for checkbox click, i have to make the form valid manually.

I tried doing `form.$valid = true;` but doesn't give me proper results.

Have any idea How to make form valid manually.

Answer (score 6):

Angular provides this functionality to you via  method on the form object that gets created.

`$valid` is a boolean, meant to be used as a read-only value.

If you would like to force the form to be valid, use `$setValidity`

from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController):

> Change the validity state, and notifies the form when the control changes validity. (i.e. it does not notify form if given validator is already marked as invalid).
>
> This method should be called by validators - i.e. the parser or formatter functions

Comment: Can i use `$setValidity` for the complete form?

Comment: I don't believe so, I think you need to handle it for each validation point on a control (i.e. email, required), and it will bubble it up to the form